# mouseleave not always triggered when my button is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code to highlight my button when mouse hover:

```
$("#fileupload").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#myLink").css("background-color", "#495461");
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $("#myLink").css("background-color", "#3C454F");
});
```

It works but when this button is clicked (so the mouse is hover) a modal window is showed to select files thus in this cas the mouseleave is never proceed.

**My question:** how to fix this to have my background color back to 'normal' (#3C454F) when this modal is showed. I prefer avoid placing some code behind the click of this button but keep everything concentrate in one bloc of code like above because here I simplify the problem...

Comment: If possible, please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: why not do this with css and avoid this altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the same behavior from `$("#fileupload').mouseleave` to `$("#myLink").click` event

Comment: Yes, as simple as that :) Thank you.

Comment: Others didn't understand what you're asking I see :)

Answer (score 2):

This should be done with CSS, and `:hover` pseudo-classes.

Just add this CSS rules to your style.

```
#myLink {
  background-color:  #495461;
}

#myLink:hover {
  background-color:  #3C454F;
}
```

Comment: Yes please, do use this solution instead of JS. This is so much easier on the ol' browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just use .hover() instead:

```
$("#fileupload").hover(
    function () {
        $("#myLink").css("background-color", "#495461");
    },
    function () {
        $("#myLink").css("background-color", "#3C454F");
    }
);
```

[jQuery Documention for .hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead, it should work.

your code should be:

```
$("#fileupload").hover(
    function () {
        $("#myLink").css("background-color", "#495461");
    },
    function () {
        $("#myLink").css("background-color", "#3C454F");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfect.

It is just colors used by you are not identified clearly. `#495461` and `#3C454F` are displayed in same shade

Check the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/4yDfT/)